# Should I return an iterator or a pointer to an element in a STL container?

Tags: c++, stl

I am developing an engine for porting existing code to a different platform. The existing code has been developed using a third party API, and my engine will redefine those third party API functions in terms of my new platform.

The following definitions come from the API:

```
typedef unsigned long shape_handle;    
shape_handle make_new_shape( int type );
```

I need to redefine `make_new_shape` and I have the option to redefine `shape_handle`.

I have defined this structure ( simplified ):

```
struct Shape
{
    int type
};
```

The Caller of `make_new_shape` doesn't care about the underlying structure of `Shape`, it just needs a "handle" to it so that it can call functions like:

```
void `set_shape_color( myshape, RED );`
```

where `myshape` is the handle to the shape.

My engine will manage the memory for the `Shape` objects and other requirements dictate that the engine should be storing `Shape` objects in a list or other iterable container.

My question is, what is the safest way to represent this handle - if the `Shape` itself is going to be stored in a std::list - an iterator, a pointer, an index?

Comment: why have you chosen std::list?

Comment: @jk - I need to be able to add and remove `Shape` objects from the middle of the container.

Comment: You definately do not want to redefine shape_handle (or make_new_shape).

Comment: @Martin, I don't agree. I really do want to redefine `make_new_shape` :-)

Comment: You just think you do. Try it I am sure you will find that you don't but it will take you ten years to realize your mistake.

Comment: @Martin. Hmm ok - you've scared me sufficiently. I'm open to ideas - seriously. Can you tell me why I shouldn't redefine `make_new_shape` and what you think I should do instead?

Comment: @martin - I can post a whole new question if it gives you more space to answer if you like.

Comment: You want to wrap shape_handle inside your own class. Then the constructor calls make_new_shape and the destructor calls the equivelent destroy. Note The shape_handle is a resource so the rule of three applies.

Comment: @Martin interesting. Ok you're suggesting I use RAII for the shape_handle, and that caller of `make_new_shape` 'owns' the memory pointed to by the new shape. I had it the other way around, my engine would "own" the memory. The reason I did it that way was because my engine has to manage the *callers* of `make_new_shape` - it puts them in a tree. The engine has to know which callers created which shapes, since it is the engine that is responsible for rendering these shapes in a specific order. It iterates through the callers - examines their lists of shapes and renders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on your representation:

- for `std::list`, use an `iterator` (not a pointer), because an `iterator` allows you to remove the element without walking the whole list.
- for `std::map` or `boost::unordered_map`, use the `Key` (of course)

Your design would be much strong if you used an associative container, because associative containers give you the ability to query for the presence of the object, rather than invoking Undefined Behavior.

Try benchmarking both `map` and `unordered_map` to see which one is faster in your case :)

Answer (score 6):

Both an iterators or a pointers will do bad stuff if you try to access them after the object has been deleted so neither is intrinsically safer. The advantage of an iterator is that it can be used to access other members of your collection.

So, if you just want to access your Shape then a pointer will be simplest. If you want to iterate through your list then use an iterator.

An index is useless in a list since std::list does not overload the [] operator.

Comment: +1: Whether you provide access to your internal representation (iterator) or not (pointer) is the most important difference.

Answer (score 3):

IIF the internal representation will be a list of Shapes, then pointers and iterators are safe. Once an element is allocated, no relocation will ever occur. I wouldn't recommend an index for obvious access performance reasons. O(n) in case of lists.

If you were using a vector, then don't use iterators or pointers, because elements can be relocated when you exceed the vectors capacity, and your pointers/iterators would become invalid.

If you want a representation that is safe regardless of the internal container, then create a container (list/vector) of pointers to your shapes, and return the shape pointer to your client. Even if the container is moved around in memory, the Shape objects will stay in the same location.

Answer (score 3):

Iterators aren't safer than pointers, but they have *much* better diagnostics than raw pointers if you're using a checked STL implementation!

For example, in a debug build, if you return a pointer to a list element, then erase that list element, you have a dangling pointer.  If you access it you get a crash and all you can see is junk data.  That can make it difficult to work out what went wrong.

If you use an iterator and you have a checked STL implementation, as soon as you access the iterator to an erased element, you get a message something like "iterator was invalidated".  That's because you erased the element it points to.  Boom, you just saved yourself potentially a whole lot of debugging effort.

So, not indices for O(n) performance.  Between pointers and iterators - *always* iterators!